# function of multiplication of two numbers. Simple

Tags: javascript, php

Help me out to run this code.

```
   function multiply(a,b) {
      return a  b;
     }
```

I try my best but not working 
Anybody can explain what is the error and  how to resolve it
Thanks

Comment: You left out the multiplication operator, `*`.

Comment: it must be `return a*b;`

Comment: `const multiply = (a, b) => a * b`

Comment: I'm puzzled by the [tag:php] tag...

Comment: you say you tried your best. What did you try? and why the `javascript` tag?

Answer (score 4):

using JavaScript

```
function multiply(a,b) {
  return a*b;
}
```

using PHP

```
function multiply($a,$b) {
  return $a*$b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not sure what you need help with but:

To multiply a number you need the `*` operator [here is a tutorial on the subject of arithmatic](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp).  Multiplication of this function would look like this:

```
function multiply(a,b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

If you don't know how to call the function you do it like this:

```
myFunction(10, 2);
```

[This page is for you](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp) as it shows you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a codewars question. You missed the `$` to declare  `a` and `b` as a variable and `*` to multiply the two variable. Next time read before attempting:

```
function multiply($a,$b) {
      return $a * $b;
     }
```

Comment: thanks for the kind reply.

Comment: Yeah.  That's a good answer now.  (sorry can't upvote again I already did). : )